# Building dynamic queries with PHP and GET parameters

Tags: php

I have three tables in my database, and I'm building an API to display the results back in JSON.

I currently have the API setup as follows:

```
api.php?type=tablename
```

I simply do:

```
$query = "SELECT * from `" . $_GET["type"] ."` ";
```

Simple enough.  I also have in there an order type:

```
api.php?type=tablename&order=columnname
```

For the code, I do:

```
$query = "SELECT * from `" . $_GET["type"] ."` ";
if(isset($_GET["order"]))
   $query .= "ORDER BY `" . $_GET["type"] . "`.`". $_GET["order"] ."` ASC";
```

Now this is fine, however I'd like to expand this so the user is able to specifically select the columns they would like using "select=columnname"

So my questions are:

- Whats the best way to have multiple selections in the URL, for example something like api.php?type=tablename&select=this|that|something

I could always explode the string and build a query that way? But is this the best method?

- Although the solution of having "`if isset`" everywhere will work, to me it gets messy, and if I want to add other SQL statements into it, it won't be easy to edit.

I saw the suggestion of using `%s` to do this, however I can't for the life of me understand how I'd implement this.

Any suggests would be nice, without doing many if statements.

EDIT: Don't worry about whether the query fails, I have that done already.

Comment: be aware of sql injections when you receive the parameters in GET method

Comment: Yeah I'd probably just explode on `|` and add them to the query in a loop

Comment: @Sundar Thanks, any suggestion on how to prevent that?

Comment: @JonathonHenderson: Or implode back using `,`, or even better `?type=tablename&select=this,that,something`.

Comment: @Alias Use `$mysqli->real_escape_string()` to prevent injections.

Comment: @geomagas Yep, depending on how simple the query is, imploding back could work just as well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1